# I want to integrate excel with cucumber. just passing workbook name

Tags: excel, cucumber, integration

I want to integrate excel with cucumber. where as i just want to pass work bood name in cucmber and run 10 scenario based on 10 rows in my workbook excel sheet. how to to do so.

```
  @are_POS_TestCase
  Scenario: BenefitPlan available in database, returns result policy available in system
    Given User hits the API "Endpoints" for search
    When Enter following Data as request parameters
      | workbookname |
      |                 |
  Then Check Status code "200"
```

detailed:
Workbook has 10 rows. i want read all rows as table and store in list. my scenarion should run 10 times and from set of rows

Answer (score 0):

If you are using cucumber with java then you can use [qaf-cucumber](https://github.com/qmetry/qaf-cucumber#qaf-cucumber) which will add capability to use [external data providers](https://qmetry.github.io/qaf/latest/maketest_data_driven.html) including excel. You need to specify data provider in you scenario as below example:

```
  @are_POS_TestCase
  @dataFile:resources/data/testdata.xls
  Scenario: BenefitPlan available in database, returns result policy available in system
    Given User hits the API "Endpoints" for search
    When Enter following Data as request parameters "${args[0]}"
    Then Check Status code "<stauscode>"
```

Furthermore, [qaf-support-ws](https://github.com/qmetry/qaf-support-ws/#qaf-support-ws) will provide ready to use steps for web-services call and verification. It has concept called [request call repository](https://github.com/qmetry/qaf-support-ws/wiki/Request-Call-Repository) that will simplify your web service test automation need by abstracting request in request call repository with full support of parameterization. If you are using it then your scenario will look like below:

```
  @are_POS_TestCase
  @dataFile:resources/data/testdata.xls
  Scenario: BenefitPlan available in database, returns result policy available in system
     When user requests "get.endpoints.call" with data "${args[0]}"
     Then response should have status code '<statuscode>'
```

NOTE: qaf-support-ws is optional and can be used for web-services test automation.